# For a 4x6 matrix m in R, is there any difference between m[1:4,] and m[,1:6]?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to understand how R goes through the elements of a matrix so I experimented with this. Evidently they are exactly the same?

```
> m <- matrix (NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
> m [, 1:6] <- 1:6
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    5    3    1    5    3
[2,]    2    6    4    2    6    4
[3,]    3    1    5    3    1    5
[4,]    4    2    6    4    2    6
> m [1:4, ] <- 1:6
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    5    3    1    5    3
[2,]    2    6    4    2    6    4
[3,]    3    1    5    3    1    5
[4,]    4    2    6    4    2    6
```

Comment: It is based on recycling of values in column order (for data.frame, matrix in R)  In the first case, you are assigning columns 1:6  with 1:6.  If you notice how it is distributed.  The number of rows is 4, so, the first four value fill the first column, then 5, 6 in second column first two rows, and then recycle from beginning.  In the second case, you are assigning rows 1 to 4.  Here, also it is going in the same direction i.e. columnwise

Comment: Is there a situation where m[, 1:6] and m[1:4, ] make a difference?

Comment: The assignment is relying on the recyling of value.  I would rather replicate the values to avoid any possible bugs

Comment: If you do want to rely on recycling, I wouldn't use either of your options but instead `m[] <- 1:6`. Or, if you are creating the matrix from scratch don't fill it with `NA` first, go straight to `matrix(1:6, nrow = 4, ncol = 6)`.These will do the whole matrix regardless of dimension, and avoid any bugs where you have a different number of rows or columns than are actually there.

Comment: I want to know if there's any difference between the two. I was only using the fill example as an experiment. Can you think of an experiment where the two differ, m[1:4,] and m[,1:6]?

Comment: `m[1:nrow_m, ]` is the whole matrix, as long a `nrow_m` is the number of rows in the matrix. `m[, 1:ncol_m]` is the whole matrix as long as `ncol_m` is the number of columns in the matrix. `m[]` is the whole matrix always. The whole matrix is the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is that for given matrix `m` (`m <- matrix (NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 6)`). Is there any difference between `m[1:4, ] <- 1:6` and `m[, 1:6] <- 1:6` then the answer is NO. This is also similar to `m [] <- 1:6` where you don't need to specify row or column index.

However, as others have already commented this involves recycling of values `1:6` and since the number of place to fill (`nrow * ncol` i.e `4 * 6 = 24`) is completely divisible by number of values supplied (`6`) this works. If you pass an uneven number of values which do not fill the matrix completely this will result in an error. For example -

```
m [1:4, ] <- 1:5
```

> Error in m[1:4, ] <- 1:5 :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

So if you are relying on recycling to fill the matrix you should be completely aware of what it is doing and side effects it can have.